# Adjust width/height of an element to fit its transformed child

Tags: html, css, transform, parent-child, responsiveness

Imaging we have an element with `transform:scale(2)`. Is there a HTML/CSS-only way to inform its parent about its transformed dimensions?

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid;
}
.child {
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transform: scale(2);
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

What I have right now is the following:

[image]

And this is what I expect to get:

[image]

---

Comment: that's not possible...

Comment: Transforms do no affect document layout. It is a visual alteration of your element, but your layout remains the same. Best way to achieve this is to either double the child's size, and scale it down if you need it to be 50% of the parent at any point, or apply the transform to the parent (but then the parent is also not taking all that extra space in the document layout).